# Git resolved conflict using previous resolution but still calls it "automatic merge failed"

Tags: git

When I run `git merge <branch>`

```
Auto-merging time_management/models.py
Auto-merging project/settings.py
Auto-merging static/js/main/components/navigation.js
Auto-merging static/js/lib/font_awesome.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in static/js/lib/font_awesome.js
Resolved 'static/js/lib/font_awesome.js' using previous resolution.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

When I opened up `static/js/lib/font_awesome.js` and could not find any outstanding conflicts.

Why is Git saying the merge failed if it resolved all the conflicts using previous resolution?

Comment: Because you're using rerere?

Comment: Yes, is that expected to result a failed automatic merge tho?

Comment: Well you're just seeing two different processes with their normal outputs, but they are interleaved. If the "Automatic merge failed" line had preceded the "Resolved" line you wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: yeah definitely wouldn't ask the question if the last 2 lines swapped order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had not been using `rerere` you would have seen:

```
Auto-merging time_management/models.py
Auto-merging project/settings.py
Auto-merging static/js/main/components/navigation.js
Auto-merging static/js/lib/font_awesome.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in static/js/lib/font_awesome.js
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

That would be normal and expected. However, `rerere` has come along as a separate process and has interleaved this line into that output:

```
Resolved 'static/js/lib/font_awesome.js' using previous resolution.
```

There's no real issue; it's just some output coming out in the "wrong" order. So don't worry, be happy.

Comment: I am feeling happier now.

Comment: As a side note, apparently the Git folks feel that when `git rerere` re-uses a recorded resolution, the result is iffy enough that you should check it manually, so Git should stop, so the internal rerere code *shouldn't* make Git assume that all is OK. I hardly ever use `rerere` myself (I keep intending to experiment more with it, but still haven't) so I'm not sure whether I agree with the Git folks here.